# Drawing a plane on a cartesian plane using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to reproduce a figure I've found on a linear algebra book using gnuplot. This is the original image [image: intersection]

You can see an intersection between two planes described by the two equations:

- 2u + v + w = 5
- 4u - 6v = -2.

I suppose that in order to plot the first equation using gnuplot I have to transform it in the form:

splot 5 - 2*x - y

where u -> x; v -> y and w -> z which is the free variable. But the result is very different from what expected. Any clue?

[image: result]

Comment: "but the result is very different from what expected" -- How so?  What did you expect?  (Also, please not the rotation of your plot compared to the original -- your x-axis points mostly to the right, theirs points "out of the page")

Comment: Are you forced using `gnuplot`?  For such figures you can obtain by far better results using other tools, e.g. the [TikZ package](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/), if you're familiar with LaTeX.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with LaTeX, in the beginning I had started using MetaPost, but compared to Gnuplot MP requires much more code. I don't know TikZ package.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you outline makes sense, however, the results may be far from what you expect.
I propose you draw single lines, using the `arrow` function in gnuplot.
This example will generate a plot very similar to the one you showed (only one plane, though):

```
set term gif
set output "demo_plane.gif"

# define your axis limits:
xmax =   6.5             
xmin =  -1.5
ymax =   8.5                 
ymin =  -1.5
zmax =   5.5
zmin =  -0.5                  
set xrange [xmin:xmax]
set yrange [ymin:ymax]
set zrange [zmin:zmax]

# remove the original axis
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset ztics

# define you data points:
x1 =  3.0
y1 = -1.0
z1 =  0.0

x2 = -1.0
y2 =  7.0
z2 =  0.0

x3 = -3.0
y3 =  7.0
z3 =  4.0

x4 =  1.0
y4 = -1.0
z4 =  4.0

# define 'arrow' without head:
set arrow 1 from x1,y1,z1 \
              to x2,y2,z2 nohead  

set arrow 2 from x2,y2,z2 \
              to x3,y3,z3 nohead  

set arrow 3 from x3,y3,z3 \
              to x4,y4,z4 nohead  

set arrow 4 from x4,y4,z4 \
              to x1,y1,z1 nohead  

# draw new axis manually (again, using arrow):
set arrow 5 from 0,0,0 \
              to 6,0,0   

set arrow 6 from 0,0,0 \
              to 0,6,0   

set arrow 7 from 0,0,0 \
              to 0,0,5 

# annotate axis labels:
set label "u" at 6.25,0,0
set label "v" at 0,6.25,0
set label "w" at 0,0,5.25

# plot will not show when empty, include dummy plot command:
set parametric 
splot x1, y1, z1 not
```

With a little rotation you will get a figure like this:

[image]

Comment: Some minor comments to your solution: You can draw the plane as polygon with `set object polygon from x1,y1,z1 to x2,y2,z2 to ...` And the labels and arrows may be drawn and placed in terms of `graph` units, e.g. `set arrow from 0,0,0 to graph 1,0,0`

Comment: @Daniele: Was this answer helpful to you?